# Get selected Node ID from RadTreeView (populated from Sql Server)

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, radtreeview

I have a TreeView that gets data from Sql Server Table. My code populates parent and child nodes successfully. 
I only want to know how to get the ID filed of the Node in a TextBox when I select any Node.

> the ID column name is : cabinetID

Here is the code I use to populate the TreeView:

```
        public void loadContainerTree()
    {
       // fMain fm = new fMain();
       // txtRepositoryID.Text = fm.repositoryID.Text;
        repositoryid = Convert.ToInt32(txtRepositoryID.Text);

        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblCabinets WHERE ParentID IS NULL AND repositoryID = @RepositoryID", conn);
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RepositoryID", repositoryid);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);

        RadTreeNode parentNode;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            parentNode = ContainersTree.Nodes.Add(dr["CabinetName"].ToString());
            PopulateTreeView(dr["CabinetID"].ToString(), parentNode);
        }
        ContainersTree.ExpandAll();
        conn.Close();
    }

    private void PopulateTreeView(string parentid, RadTreeNode parentNode)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adapterchild = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblCabinets WHERE ParentID = @ParentID AND repositoryID = @RepositoryID", conn);
        adapterchild.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParentID", parentid);
        adapterchild.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RepositoryID", repositoryid);
        DataTable dtchild = new DataTable();
        adapterchild.Fill(dtchild);

        foreach(DataRow dr in dtchild.Rows)
        {
            RadTreeNode childNode;
            if (parentNode == null)
            {
                childNode = ContainersTree.Nodes.Add(dr["cabinetName"].ToString());
            }
            else
            {

                childNode = parentNode.Nodes.Add(dr["cabinetName"].ToString());
                PopulateTreeView(dr["cabinetID"].ToString(), childNode);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using Tag property?

Comment: I tried this code" CurrentNodeID.Text = ContainersTree.SelectedNode.Tag.ToString(); " but i got this error "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

Comment: I really need an answer to my question please..

Comment: In your `Populate TreeView` function you do not set `tag` to it but then you try to use `tag` with `CurrentNodeId.Text = tag`

Answer (score 0):

Basic workflow with `TreeView/Tag` or any other control.

First of all `Tag is an Object that contains data about the control. The default is null` which means we can use tag to store `string` or `int` or any `CustomClass`

Now let's create `Custom class` like this:

```
public class Cabinet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // Any other value
}
```

Now we will get data from our database and store it into tree node like this:

```
public static void AddNodeToTreeView(this TreeView tv, string Text, Cabinet cabinet)
{
    TreeNode n = new TreeNode();
    n.Text = Text;
    n.Tag = cabinet;
    tv.Add(n);
}
```

We call this like this:

```
Cabinet c = new Cabinet();
c.Id = 1;//You can store data from sql here
c.Name = "Some Name"; //You can store data from sql here
yourTreeView.AddNodeToTreeView("SomeTextTOBeDisplayed", c);
```

And now all you need to do is get Node you need either from event:

```
private void treeView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Cabinet c = yourTreeView.SelectedNode.Tag as Cabinet;

    // Here do whatever you want with data
}
```

or from loop:

```
foreach(TreeNode n in yourTreeView.Nodes)
{
    Cabinet c = n.Tag as Cabinet;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you kind reply, but could you please explain your answer in relevance to my code above.

Comment: @EmadMohamed apply it to your code. Problem in your code is you never assign object into `Tag` property but then you use `Tag` and it returns `System.NullReferenceException`